# Прибавить к дате дни не изменяя сам объект DateTime

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Задача состоит в следующем: нужно записать в  массив дату начала и конца.
Некоторое количество элементов могут иметь одинаковые даты конца и начала(за это отвечает переменная `$condition`). Как только количество таких элементов становится равно `$condition`, дата начала следующего элемента сдвигается на `$countDays`. В переменной `$from` изначально хранится объект `DateTime` - первоначальная точка отсчёта.

Проблема в том, что я применяю `modify` к объекту дважды, и в обоих случаях объект изменяется. Мне же нужно сделать таким образом, что бы в первом условии в `$data[$key]['end']` записался объект `DateTime` с датой больше на `$duration` дней, но сам объект при этом не изменился. А уже во втором условии объект должен изменятся, и уже в следующей итерации `$duration` должно прибавлятся относительно изменного объекта.

Чем можно замениь `modify` в первом случае, что бы не изменять объект `$from`?

```
$j = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $duration = self::getDuration($value);
            if ($duration) {
                $data[$key]['begin'] = $from;
                $data[$key]['end'] = $from->modify('+' . $duration . ' day');
                $j++;
                if ($j >= $condition) {
                    $from->modify('+' . $countDays . ' day');
                    $j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, можете клонировать объект $from в первом случае. Будет что-то типа $cloneFrom = clone $from; (Либо  (clone $from)->modify(...) ) А во втором случае использовать оригинальный $from.
Так же для удобства можете в цикле сделать if(!$duration){continue;} (Так читабильней и лаконичней)

Comment: Хороший вариант, пока так и сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо DateTime можно использовать DateTimeImmutable

> Данный класс ведет себя аналогично классу DateTime, за исключением того, что он никогда не изменяет себя, а вместо этого возвращает новый объект. http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetimeimmutable.php

```
$data[$key]['begin'] = DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($from);
$data[$key]['end'] = $data[$key]['begin']->modify('+' . $duration . ' day');
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, можете клонировать объект **$from** в первом случае. Будет что-то типа **$cloneFrom = clone $from;** (Либо **(clone $from)->modify(...) )** А во втором случае использовать оригинальный $from. Так же для удобства можете в цикле сделать

```
if(!$duration){ //Так читабильней и лаконичней
  continue;
 }
```